# Something kills my screens

Tags: 17.10, systemd, background-process

My screen sessions are getting killed when I log out. How can I prevent this?

I have already set:

```
KillUserProcesses=no
```

in `/etc/systemd/logind.conf`. When I log back in, I get the "wipe" option in screen. This problem is made quite apparent by another bug which forcibly logs me out every time I turn off the monitor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this works on 17.10 but on 18.04 I had the same issue. It seems to be because of changes on logind cleaning up processes (preventing any user session process persisting). Apparently KillUserProcesses=no is the default in 18.04 (according to the comments in /etc/systemd/logind.conf) so instead I added my user to the KillExcludeUsers list:

```
KillExcludeUsers=root YOUR_USERNAME
```

Next I ran the command:

```
sudo loginctl enable-linger YOUR_USERNAME
```

and finally rebooted. After that my screen session would persist after a detach.

Comment: The second line fixed it for me, thanks! I think `KillUserProcesses=no`
 does the same as `KillExcludeUsers=root YOUR_USERNAME`, but it's a bit more blunt solution.